# Signing an ipa file using Enterprise Account Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS application development. I have an Enterprise Account and I successfully added that Provisioning Profile to my Mac.

My understanding is that an iOS application signed with an Enterprise Account's certificate can be installed on any number of iOS devices within that organization.

I already have an .ipa file which is signed with a different certificate (not using the enterprise one that I have). I need to sign this application with the enterprise account that I have with me. Is it possible to do this? Or what should I need to sign the application using my Enterprise Account' certificate? Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can resign the IPA by unzipping it and replacing the embedded mobile provisioning profile with your enterprise provisioning profile.

Afterwards, resign the .app directory using codesign and your enterprise distribution certificate. Codesign is a commandline tool that comes with Xcode.

Finally, you zip the IPA back up and distribute it in the normal way for an Enterprise app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the certificate and mobileprovision while archiving the app. Then in Organizer, "distribute" the app and select the option to "Save for Enterprise or Adhoc distribution"

Comment: I think @Apps don't have source code with him.

Comment: that is correct, I don't have the source code with me.